# Error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: mysql, jsp, jdbc

I'm working on jsp code and have a problem with my db connection. I have two table in my database , `ANN` and `SEC` which `SEC_ID` is `primary key` and `auto increment` in `SEC` table and `foreign key` in `ANN` table. I want to use this query in my code

```
(SELECT 
   DATE, 
   MESSAGE 
FROM ANN 
WHERE ANN.SEC_ID = SEC.SEC_ID;)
```

But when I'm running my program , I've got
this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException
```

Comment: You havent joined ANN to SEC

Comment: `SELECT DATE, MESSAGE FROM ANN, SEC WHERE ANN.SEC_ID = SEC.SEC_ID;`

Comment: Besides the weird placement of parentheses in your query, it is either incomplete (you didn't post the full code), or the missing part of the query in itself is the cause of the problem)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with joining the tables. You may use the following:

```
SELECT 
   A.DATE, # Assuming both DATE and MESSAGE are in ANN table 
   A.MESSAGE 
FROM 
   ANN AS A
   JOIN SEC AS S ON (A.SEC_ID = S.SEC_ID);
```

(I have used alias for performance and readability)

Remember you can also do:

```
SELECT 
   A.DATE, # Assuming both DATE and MESSAGE are in ANN table 
   A.MESSAGE 
FROM 
   ANN AS A, SEC AS S 
WHERE A.SEC_ID = S.SEC_ID;
```

But it is memory ineffient. The number of rows retrieved from database is:

**Number of rows in ANN * Number of rows in SEC**

That is not obviously not what you want. If you have a few thousand row in each table, then even you will get `OutOfMemoryError` from MySQL

Answer (score 0):

The problem is just with the placement of the semicolon ';'
Just check this out :

```
(SELECT 
   DATE, 
   MESSAGE 
FROM ANN 
WHERE ANN.SEC_ID = SEC.SEC_ID) ;
```